# How do I put multiple excel rows into one big list with sublists?

Tags: python, excel, list, rows, openpyxl

How do you take multiple excel rows and put them into one big list with sublists for each excel row? I've used openpyxl to extract the data from a .xlsx file and then used .iter_rows to get all the needed rows' values like so:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

workbook = load_workbook(filename=r"C:\Users\file.xlsx")
sheet = workbook.active

for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2,
                           max_row=21,
                           min_col=1,
                           max_col=4,
                           values_only=True):
    print(row)
    listtest = []
    for cell in row:
        listtest.append(cell)

print(listtest)
```

I tried using this method, but it only makes the last line into a list, giving me an output like this:

> (1, 1, 12, 4)
>
> (2, 1, 8, 3)
>
> ...
>
> ...
>
> (20, 101, 3, 11)
>
> [20, 101, 3, 11]

I'm trying to get an output like this:

> [['1', '1', '12', '4'], ['2', '1', '8', '3'], ... , ['20', '101', '3', '11']]

Would make my day if someone could budge me in the right direction here :)
Thanks.

Comment: `values = [list(row) for row in sheet.iter_rows(…)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're overwriting `listtest` in each iteration of your loop. To stick to your original code (with a slight modification), try:

```
output = []
for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2,
                           max_row=21,
                           min_col=1,
                           max_col=4,
                           values_only=True):
    listtest = []
    for cell in row:
        listtest.append(cell)
    output.append(listtest)
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked too. How would you make every int into str using this method?

Comment: You could use `listtest.append(str(cell))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\file.xlsx")
list_of_lists = df.applymap(str).to_numpy().tolist()
```

This should return what you are looking for.

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much :) This worked. Is there a simple way to add apostrophes around each number in each list like [['1', '1', '12', '4']]? Thanks again.

Comment: You can use `df.applymap(str)` to convert all elements to `str` before converting the dataframe into a list of lists. See the edit.